# phpmyadmin store prodcedure call with input value

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
Begin
   Select MAX(score) from score, student where student.student_id = score.student_id and event_id = eventid;
End
```

when I create that, how can I call it with input value `eventid=`1?

Comment: I can run the function Select MAX(score) from score, student where student.student_id = score.student_id and event_id = 1, correctly.. However I dont know how to input the parameters when I call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way, just use call the function name(1 which is the eventid value)